# How can we access the java security package in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I need to access the security package in Java using Jmeter on Bean Shell. Is there anyway to do this ?

I have got error like this.

```
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import android.util.Base64.*; import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
```

Help on this is useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with `import android.util.Base64.*` - android package is not part of Java. You probably meant to have

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

Note that you need to have Java 8

Comment: Thanks @Kriril. I have been using that JAR from android because the app uses that JAR for some encryption process. Hence i have used import java.util.Base64;

Comment: if it helped you, please accept the answer, since then it will be helpful for others.